Need Help To Prove Fullness of a Functor
I am working on proving the following proposition

A functor $F:\mathscr{A} \rightarrow \mathscr{B}$ is an equivalence of categories if and only if it is faithfull, full and essentially surjective.

So far I have the following,
($\implies$) Suppose $F$ to be an equivalence categories. We want to show that $F$ is faithfull, full and essentially surjective.
Faithfull: Let $A,A'$ be two objects in $\mathscr{A}$ and $f: A \longrightarrow A'$ a morphism in $\mathscr{A}$.
Sejam $F: A \rightarrow A'$ with $F(f)=F(g)$.
By definition, there exists a natural isomorphism $\alpha: 1_\mathscr{A} \longrightarrow G \circ F$. So, we can build the following diagram,

that commutes. So, for any $g,g': A \longrightarrow A'$ where $GF(g)=GF(g')$ we have that $g=g'$.
Essentially surjective: Because $\mathscr{A}, \mathscr{B}$ are equivalent categories, be definition, there exists a natural isomorphism $\beta: B \longrightarrow F(G(B))$, and consequently exists an isomorphism $\beta': FG(B) \longrightarrow B$. Note that $G(B)$ is equal to some $A \in \mathscr{A}$, so we have an isomorphism $\beta'': F(A) \longrightarrow B$.
However I am having some doubt in proving the fullness of this functor, and so I was wondering if anyone has any tips for me.
Thank for all the help in advance!
EDIT: 

Hint: What can you say about the function $\operatorname{Hom}{A'}(X, Y) \to \operatorname{Hom}{A'}(FG(X), FG(Y))$, $f \mapsto \beta_Y \circ f \circ \beta^{-1}_X$? How does it compare to $f \mapsto FG(f)$?

So, basically, all I need to do to verify surjectivity is to build the square (check the edit!) and verify that $FG(f)$ can be written as $\beta_{B'} \circ f \circ \beta_B^{-1}$?

For fullness: if $f:F(A)\to F(A')$ is an arrow, $G(f):GF(A)\to GF(A')$ has a clear associated $g:=\alpha_{A'}^{-1}\circ G(f)\circ \alpha_A:A\to A'$. Motivation: this is the only thing you can really write down! How else can we go from $A$ to $GF(A)$?
Now we would like to argue that $F(g)=f$. Maybe this is unclear, but we know from faithfulness it suffices to argue $GF(g)=G(f)$. But recall $G(f)=\alpha_{A'}\circ g\circ\alpha_A^{-1}$, so it suffices to show $GF(g)\circ\alpha_A=\alpha_{A'}\circ g$. But by naturality of $\alpha$, this is certainly true!
